# Wordpress broken Woocommerce product image link fixing

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

When i deploy my woocommerce site from my local the all products image is break. How can i get rid from this problem???

[image]

Comment: did you check: All the images exists on you local, and the absolute url of the images is modified to your local?

Comment: it could also be a matter of chmod 777  the images directory

Comment: One word: [srdb3](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB)

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome console developer to see the relative path of the image and see if that matches up with the actual path. Most likely that is the culprit. If it is that you have to match the URI to the img directory. Without a jsfiddle I can't really tell you.

Comment: This is not really an answer, and should be a comment.